# injecting the d3.js graphs correctly when using Angular directive multiple times with bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, d3.js

I created a directive to display my d3.js charts and for design reasons I need to use it twice in the same layout because the design should look different for mobile devices. This is the HTML (Jade):

```
// Jade / Pug template:
[...]
.row.visible-xs
  .mobile-top
    //- Chart for mobile
    account-chart
.row.hidden-lg.hidden-xl
  .col-sm-12
    [...]

.row
  .col-lg-4.col-md-5.col-sm-6.p-xs-reset
    //- Chart for tablets and up
    .hidden-xs
      account-chart
[...]
```

Angular Directive:

```
app.directive('chart', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: '/angular/chart',
    link: function(scope) {

      var data = scope.data;

      if (data) {
        init();
      }

      function init() { ... }
```

The result is that in the mobile size I see 2 charts and in the "tablets and up" size I don't see nothing...

What I'm doing wrong?

Here is a pen about the issue: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQwppE

Comment: Added a Pen about the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the fact you targeted the elements with an ID attribute, which should be unique for each element (that's why both SVGs got appended to the first chart)

`Angular` have another parameter to the `link` function which gives you the component DOM element reference.

you need each chart component to give itself as the HTML to inject the graph in (you can also give a sub HTML element)

I changed the background to pink on the xs version to make it clearer

The main change is in these two lines:

```
link: function(scope, element) {
  // ...
  //initialize SVG
  svg = d3.select(element[0]).append('svg');
  // ...
}
```

Here's your codepen fixed: https://codepen.io/neilkalman/pen/YezVOq?editors=0010

Comment: Glad I could help :-)

Answer (score -1):

This problem isn't actually a AngularJS problem. You have to ensure, that the template of your directive/ the html part of your directive is responsive.

If this is ensured (responsive html part of your directive), wherever you use your directive it will adapt to the given space.

Comment: It adapt correctly, if I don't use a directive, writing just "Hello Mobile" and "Hello Tablets and up" I can see it correctly displayed while resizing the window... Using a directive, with just the same text returning, I can see only the one on top... It looks like it load only the first.

Comment: I updated the question, I think now it is more clear to understand, thanks.

Comment: I also added a pen about the issue.

Comment: As I understand the timeframe, this was posted before a lot of the changes to the original question, but I think this is more of a comment than an answer